# checkbox is checked without select it

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-listview

In my listview I have a view with checkbox and sounds. When I select one checkbox others is selected too and I don´t know why.

In this video I show the problem:

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2iu5mn_aplication_tech

What can I do? This is my code

custom_view.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"

    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/text1"/>

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Custom ArrayAdapter.java

```
private class myArrayAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

 private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> myChecked = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();

    public myArrayAdapter2(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

        for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++){
            myChecked.put(i, false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;


        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textview = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textview.setText(myList.get(position));
        CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    ruta.add(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() 
                        + "/test/" + myList.get(position)
                        );
                 } else {
                    shared = ruta.indexOf(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() 
                        + "/test/" + myList.get(position)
                        );
                    ruta.remove(shared);
                }
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
}
```

And this is the buttonlistener code:

```
public void AudioClick(View view) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/test");
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++){
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }

        ArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.custom_textview,
            android.R.id.text1,
            myList
        );

        listvi.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.  It is too hard to read.

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I would say that the checkboxes that are being checked when the first one is checked are actually the same check box. Make sure that all of your check boxes are different objects.

Comment: Sorry I fix it in 1 minute. Thanks

Comment: you must go through some tutorial for this              http://www.javatpoint.com/android-checkbox-example

Comment: Thanks  Md Hussain, I´m going to review it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your video it's seen that selection is occurring at proper intervals. So the problem should be, your `convertView` getting reused.

It is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865169/android-listview-using-viewholder).

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works) to understand Listview's recycling.

I would also recommend using a [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder).